# Incompatible Data Types Error

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am "attempting" to make a method that will take my string array and compare it to an answer key that I have imported from a data file.  Every time I compile I get this incompatible data type error and it is saying that:

Found: java.lang.String
Required: java.lang.String[][]

Am I not doing that?
I have had no luck searching for a solution on here and on Google.  They seem to be irrelevant to what I am trying to accomplish.

```
import java.util.*;  // Allows for the input of a scanner method.
import java.io.*;    // Allows for the inputting and outputting of a data file.
import java.lang.*;  // Allows for the use of String Methods.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class TESTY
{
static Scanner testanswers;
static PrintWriter testresults;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    testanswers = new Scanner(new FileReader("TestInput.dat"));
    testresults = new PrintWriter("TestOutput.dat");

    String StudentID;
    String answers;
    // Reads first two lines first to know how many records there are.
    String answerKey = testanswers.nextLine();
    int count = Integer.parseInt(testanswers.nextLine());

    // Allocate the array for the size needed.
    String[][] answerArray = new String[count][];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        String line = testanswers.nextLine();
        answerArray[i] = line.split(" ", 2);
    }

    for(int row = 0; row < answerArray.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < answerArray[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(answerArray[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
    gradeData(answerArray, answerKey);



    testanswers.close();
    testresults.close();

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Method: gradeData
//Description: This method will grade testanswers showing 
//what was missed, skipped, letter grade, and percentage.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static double gradeData(String[][] answerArray, String answerKey)
{   

    String key;
    double Points = 0;
    StringBuilder[] wrongAnswers = new StringBuilder[answerArray.length];

    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < answerArray.length; rowIndex++)
    {
        String studAnswers[][] = answerArray[rowIndex][1].replace(" ", "S");
        for(int charIndex = 0; charIndex < studAnswers[rowIndex][1].length; charIndex++)
        {
            if(studAnswers[rowIndex][1].charAt(charIndex).equals(key.charAt(charIndex)))
            {
                Points += 2;
            }
            if(!studAnswers[rowIndex][1].charAt(charIndex).equals('S'))
            {
                Points --;
            }
            else
            {
                wrongAnswers.setcharAt(charIndex, 'X');
            }
        }
    }
    return Points;


}
```

To get a better idea of what I am doing here is my .dat file:

```
TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT
5
ABC54301 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT
SJU12874 TTTFFTFFFTFTFFTTFTTF
KSPWFG47 FT  FT  FTFTFFTTFFTF
PAR38501 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
MCY19507 TTTT TTTT TTTT TT TT
```

Comment: More information would help...such as what line the compiler errors on.

Comment: This errors are occurs starting at line 73 inside the grade method.  It is where I am trying to set studentAnswers[][] to my answerArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement, for instance,

```
String studAnswers[][] = answerArray[rowIndex][1].replace(" ", "S");
```

gives the compilation error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[][]
```

because

`answerArray[rowIndex][1].replace(" ", "S");` returns a `String`.

- `answerArray` is a 2D `String` array.
- `answerArray[rowIndex][1]` gets
  a element from the array which is a string
- `answerArray[rowIndex][1].replace...` replaces a character in that
  `String` with another character, ending up as another `String` (with
  the replaced character)

You are trying to assign it to a `String` array.

Also, you cannot use `equals` on primitives (`int`, `char`...). You need to use `==` for comparison.

Comment: Thanks, alot of great help with your response. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String studAnswers[][] = answerArray[rowIndex][1].replace(" ", "S");
```

Here, `studAnswers` is declared as an array of arrays of Strings, and you initialize it with a String. Indeed, `answerArray` is an array of arrays of Strings, and `answerArray[rowIndex][1]` is thus a String. And you replace every white space in this String by an S, which returns another String.

That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have changed to String studAnswers = answerArray[rowIndex][1].replace(" ", "S");  I have realized that error there.  The idea to replace white space with S was to fill blank answers with the S for grading purposes.